# How to add new tab to any custom extension?

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides, menu, tabs

I have one previously installed extension which have 3 tabs already added , Now  I want to add new tab below it , How can I achieve this . I want to add new tab regions .

```
 <adminhtml>
     <rewrite>
    <customer_edit_tabs>Netbiz_Post_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs</customer_edit_tabs>
     </rewrite>    </adminhtml>
```

I have gone through this but not able to figure out what should I place in place of  .

I want to add new tab to aw_blog extension (add post view) .

Please suggest.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to solve this issue, I am posting an answer so that it might be helpful to someone.

In my custom modules config.xml file I have added

```
<blocks>
            <post>
                <class>Netbiz_Post_Block</class>
            </post>
            <blog>
                <rewrite>
                    <manage_blog_edit_tabs>Netbiz_Post_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs</manage_blog_edit_tabs>
                </rewrite>
            </blog>
        </blocks>
```

here manage_blog_edit_tabs point towards the class file which is responsible for adding tabs (in my case AW_Blog_Block_Manage_Blog_Edit_Tabs class) . I have override the `_beforeToHtml()` method of that class to add new menu item.

```
<?php

class Netbiz_Post_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs extends AW_Blog_Block_Manage_Blog_Edit_Tabs
{
    protected $parent;

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
            $this->parent =parent::_beforeToHtml();
            $this->addTab('regions_section', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('blog')->__('Regions'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('blog')->__('Regions'),
            'content' => $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('post/adminhtml_post_form')->toHtml(),
        ));
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

This adds the new menu for me.

Hope this helps someone.